# Filtrar datos importados por gspread Python 3.x

Tags: python, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-sheets

Estoy importando datos de una planilla de Google Sheets, pero necesito filtrar algunas filas y no cargar todas. Alguien maneja esta librería, y sabe si existe algún argumento para filtrar filas.

Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma hasta el momento:

```
    import gspread
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

    scope=['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds=ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Python-                        cbe875b7fd9f.json', scope)
    client=gspread.authorize(creds)
    sheet=client.open('Prueba Python').sheet1
    preventivos=sheet.get_all_records()
    print(preventivos)
```

Esto lo hago ya que hay una columna que tiene varias opciones por ejemplo opción "NOGO", "MOC" y "AHM". Quiero importar solo aquellas filas que tengan la opción "AHM". De esta forma la carga será más rápida ya que ahora demora varios segundos y hay mucha data que no me interesa importar.

Archivo de ejemplo:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PWKujfqoMpdecMWNxGRxPQoA4RtmZeMVBemH6rXfVF8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo los quieres filtrar?

Comment: Hola @César podría compartir el archivo para que lo vean, pero hay una columna que tiene varias opciones por ejemplo opción "NOGO", "MOC" y "AHM". Quiero importar solo aquellas filas que tengan la opción "AHM". De esta forma yo creo la carga será más rápida ya que ahora demora varios segundos y hay mucha data que no me interesa importar.

Comment: Jorge, agrega esa información a tu pregunta, recuerda que mientras más información, mejor.

Comment: OK @César Listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jorge, la documentación de esta librería indica para la rutina 
`get_all_records()`:

> Returns a list of dictionaries, all of them having: the contents of
>   the spreadsheet’s with the head row as keys, And each of these
>   dictionaries holding - the contents of subsequent rows of cells as
>   values.

Es decir una lista de diccionarios dónde cada clave es el encabezado de la columna. Algo como lo siguiente, tomando como base tu ejemplo:

```
lista = [
          {"B/C": "T00APSUL",   "NOMBRE": "PREVENTIVO", "FECHA": "2016-10-07 00:07:55", "AVION": "CC-BAS", "FLOTA": "A320C", "ATA": "550" , "DESCRIPCION": "NO GO VIBRATION REPORTED BY PIREP", "H1": "COMPLETE", "FUENTE": "NOGO"},
          {"B/C": "T00AQ4HM",   "NOMBRE": "PREVENTIVO", "FECHA": "2016-10-08 10:40:26", "AVION": "CC-BGG", "FLOTA": "B787", "ATA": "45" , 
           "DESCRIPCION": "DSO REQUEST R/R ENGINE DATA ACMF REPORT DOES NOT DOWNLINK", "H1": "COMPLETE", "FUENTE": "AHM"}
        ]
```

No transcribí todos los registros, hay que ver también el comportamiento frente a columnas sin encabezados, por ejemplo la que sería la columna `H` de tu planilla. Con estos datos el filtro es algo como esto:

```
print([e for e in lista if e["FUENTE"] == "AHM"])
```

Es decir, retornamos las filas dónde en la columna "FUENTE" encontramos el texto "AHM".

Comment: De hecho, `get_all_records()` retorna una lista diccionarios, no una lista de listas: "Returns a list of dictionaries, ...". Tal vez te estás confundiendo con `get_all_values()`

Comment: Eso iba a decir, ya que retorna diccionarios. Al adaptar tu ejemplo Patricio no me funciona

Comment: Es cierto @Cesar, me confundí con `get_all_values`.

Comment: Pero lo estamos imprimiendo de forma distinta, de igual forma estamos leyendo todos los datos de la planilla cierto ?

Comment: @JorgePonti no parace haber una forma de filtrar **desde** Google, al parecer solo es disponible filtrar celdas. Si quieres filtrar el resultado me parece que tienes que hacerlo por tu lado, después de haber obtenido los resultados.

Comment: @Cesar, voy a editar la respuesta en un rato, salvo que ya la tengas escrita, etonces la elimino. Saludos

Comment: Patricio, no tengo respuesta. Me parece que la solución va por este camino que estás planteando, filtrar los resultados luego de obtenerlos desde Google, no creo que haya otra forma.

Comment: Yo pensé en otra cosa, pero seria para otra pregunta hacer un script en Google sheets que filtre ne otra hoja los datos que quiero importar. Lo malo que no estoy muy bien relacionado a javascript

Comment: Hay una librería que lo relaciona con Pandas quizás con Pandas sea más fácil filtrar

Comment: Jorge, ahí modifiqué la respuesta, como verás tampoco es que sea demasiado complejo. La única ventaja de filtrar por un `G-Script` es que evitas hacer viajar todos los registros, pero no tengo nada claro como sería.